# Why are my new users in SonarQube created with active=NULL?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have just installed SonarQube 4.5, connected to a Postgres database.

Everything seems to be working just fine with respect to code analysis, but when I create new users, either through the Setting screen or the sign up form, the user is created with **'active'** set to null in the database. If I update **'active'** to **true** manually, I can use the new user and everything seems fine.

The **'active'** column on **'users'** does have default set to true.

There are other instances of SonarQube using the same database, each with their own schema.  Because of this I had some initial difficulties with the installation and had to do some parts of the DB migration manually, so I'm assuming I missed something but I don't know anything about Rails so it's hard for me to debug.

I don't know for sure if any of this is related, but here is the process I went through to get SonarQube running:

Early in it's bootstrap process, Rails was apparently able to find a **'schema_migrations'** table from one of the other schemas, but then when it tried to select from **'schema_migrations'** (in the correct schema) it couldn't find it, so an exception was thrown and the database setup aborted. So, I created a **'schema_migrations'** table in my schema with a single column 'version,' restarted Sonar, and it was now in a state where it thought it was doing a version upgrade and started the database migration.

The migration failed in **'011_create_administrator.rb'**, because it was trying to insert NULL into the **'active'** column of **'users'**, and that column had not been created yet. So, I manually ran the insert without the **'active'** part, updated **'schema_migrations.version'** to 11, and restarted.

The migration started again, and failed now in **'530_merge_measure_data_into_project_measures.rb'** with

```
"Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.MeasureDataMigration
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column m.measure_data does not exist."
```

So, I added the **'measure_data'** column to **'project_measures'**, and restarted. Now the migration completed successfully, SonarQube started normally, and I was able to log in as admin and get started analyzing code.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't modify the database, things should work out of the box when installing a fresh SonarQube instance on a fresh DB.

So I'd advise you to restart from scratch:

- Drop your schema in Postgres and create a new one with access granted to the "sonar" user
- Start SQ on this new schema
- And everything should be working fine

Comment: Maybe they should, but they didn't in this case.

Comment: If you start from a fresh install of SonarQube and a fresh Postgres DB, then you must be missing something because we have integration tests that run on Postgres every day and that start from a fresh DB.

Comment: Is it a supported configuration to have multiple independant SonarQube instances using the same Postgres DB, but with different schemas?  And yes I have the search path set correctly as per the documentation.

Comment: 1 SonarQube instance = 1 DB. The clustering will be supported in a near feature, watch http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5391

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking about clustering. These are completely independent instances, but they use the same database _server_. But, each instance has it's own _user_ and _schema_ in the database, the search path is set correctly, and each user only has privileges on their own schema.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is probably to create a dedicated database for SonarQube to use, but in the meantime I have worked around the issue by using this trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION activate_user() RETURNS trigger as $activate_user$
    BEGIN
        IF (NEW.active IS NULL) THEN
            NEW.active := true; 
        END IF;

        RETURN NEW;
    END;    
$activate_user$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER activate_user_trigger BEFORE INSERT on fst_sonar.users
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE activate_user();

    commit;
```